# Operator error when printing array and avoiding nulls

Tags: java

Im trying to print out details from an array but avoid printing out the nulls, here is my short code, can anybody see why im getting the error "! operator cannot be applied to fiction" and "! operator cannot be applied to nonfiction"

```
case 2:
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
        if (!fictionArray[i] = null){
            System.out.println(fictionArray);
        }
        if (!nonfictionArray[i] = null){
            System.out.println(nonfictionArray);
        }
    }

    break;
```

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` is equality. `!=` is non-equality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `fictionArray[i] != null`. `=` is the assignment operator. `!` is the logical `not` operator. It only applies to boolean expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some valid syntax

```
if (fictionArray[i] != null)
```

or

```
if (!(fictionArray[i] == null))
```

Answer (score 1):

make it `fictionArray[i] != null`

Answer (score 1):

**!= operator**

Checks if the values of two operands are equal or not, if values are not equal then condition becomes true.

```
                    if (fictionArray[i] != null){
```

Or

```
                    if (nonfictionArray[i] != null){
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `if (!fictionArray[i] = null)` to `if (fictionArray[i] != null)`

and

change `if (!nonfictionArray[i] = null)` to `if (nonfictionArray[i] != null)`